# What does this find command with options mean?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

When i run this command in Debian

```
sudo find . ! -name . -type d -or -type f
```

It lists all the files in the current path, but not the directories, so I think I know what it does.

But what does the `-name .` part do?

All names in the directory? is this a valid use of -name? I don't see this documented in `man find`.

Also what is the `-or` doing here? I don't see it listing any directories when i run the command.

thanks

Comment: "but not the directories" – Are you sure? Create a subdirectory and try again.

Comment: Yes, directories and subdirectories are not listed, only files.

Comment: @Tlink are you absolutely sure about that? On my machine with GNU find it will list both files and directories and their subdirectories, just as expected with the given options.

Comment: You're right, GNU does, if you can try on a mac or a different shell, please confirm that you get different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the exclamation mark before the `-name` option, it is interchangable with the `-not` option. It will behave like a logical NOT and negate the following option.

In this case your command would search for all files and directories, starting from the current directory, with a name that is NOT `.`.

It basically does the same as `find . -name "*" -type d -or -type f` would do, with the exception that it won't print the current directory as a search result:

```
╭─user@machine ~/somedir ‹master●› 
╰─$ find . -name "*" -type d -or -type f               
.
╭─user@machine ~/somedir ‹master●› 
╰─$ find . ! -name . -type d -or -type f               
╭─user@machine ~/somedir ‹master●› 
╰─$
```